# How To Freeze Frame On A Falling Leaf (Dynamics & Forces)?

Tags: physics, rigid-body-simulation, force-fields

I want to create a shot where a fallen leaf ends up in front of the camera, freezes there for a few seconds, and then resumes its fall.

[image]

I'm trying to do this with physics and forces, but I can't get the leaf to fall and tumble very elegantly, and I don't know how to direct an object into the "sweet spot" in order to freeze time.  For some reason when I turn on "Animated" in the Rigid Body settings the object no longer responds to physics.

**And in particular I don't know how to coddle the physics in order for the leaf to end up exactly where I want it in the frame.**

Would love it if one of you gurus could just roughly outline for me the way you would approach this.

Comment: why do you want to fight with physics if you can do it in VSE for free? in vse you just would make two cuts to cut out your video, so that you have one frame, then move the end a bit to right and extend this one frame like so: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NmQbM.png

Comment: maybe you should elaborate a bit more what you exactly want to achieve. should just the leave "freeze" or the complete "animation" freeze? The animated button does exactly this: it turns off physics and you have to keyframe the object. If you turn it on, Blender will animate it. You can change this behaviour each frame. But there is no in-between for these states. Either you keyframe it (animated on) or you let Blender do its physics (keyframe off)

Comment: @chris is there no way to convert a particle system into keyframes?  I've got my sim working fine now except for the slowing down time part where the leaf pauses in front of the camera and then resumes falling. I want it to be a smooth motion, not a sudden stop.  I've gone into Premiere and done some Time Remapping with Optical Flow, but the other issue is that my animation has motion blur, so remapping the time doesn't look great because it slows down a blurry image. I could disable motion blur of course and add some in post but that never looks as good.

Comment: Even this you could achieve with VSE. There is an effect strip "time control" for this. You might have to render some "in between" frames that is doesn't stutter. But of course there are always several ways to achieve an effect.

Comment: Agree with @Chris, completely. For effect, you could even mask out the leaf if you wanted, so it would freeze, against a background which had moving elements in it, if you wanted.

Comment: OK @chris then perhaps I am unsure of how the VSE works in Blender.  I assumed it was the same principle as any other NLE in that you render a sequence of images and then sequence them... but you're making it sound like it works more as a compositor?  Sadly for me the VSE is not an appealing solution since I am unfamiliar with it (yet I do have 20+ years experience with After Effects, Premiere, etc).

Comment: @GlenCandle: i know. Blender is an amazing software and it is free....but unfortunately it isn't intuitive. And some things are hard to learn. VSE is for sure one of them. And NLA as well. But once you get familiar with it - you will love it. I needed my time to learn them too and still - i just know 15 % of it. I have no experience at all with AE, Premiere or any other 3D software.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need a particle system for a single leaf? You say in the comments you got the simulation working fine. Then this is all you need.

1. Go to the *Scene Properties* > *Rigid Body World* and make sure the simulation like you want it is baked with either pressing *Bake* or *Bake All Dynamics* (if you haven't already).

[image: bake dynamics]

2. Then choose *Object > Rigid Body > Bake to Keyframes* from the menu in the *3D Viewport*.

[image: bake to keyframes]

3. You'll get an options window where you can choose the frame range how much of the simulation you want to have baked (note: after that the *Rigid Body* physics are removed from the object).

[image: bake range]

4. Now you have keyframes for *Location* and *Rotation* on each frame of the selected range that you can tweak to your liking by moving them away from each other where you want to pause the animation - of course you need to copy the keyframe where you stop to the frame where you want to resume the animation. For a smooth motion you can use Bézier interpolation between the key frames - well I guess this takes some work with moving or maybe scaling the keyframes.

[image: graph editor]

5. The good thing is, these keyframes are now relative to the coordinates of a superordinate system, i.e. if you parent the leaf to an empty, you can tweak the position and rotation of the leaf by moving the empty, and the animation will always be relative to the empty's location and rotation (and even the scale).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gordonbrinkmann, but it doesn't work on my particle system.  I have my sim working *as a particle system* not as a rigid body system.  If I could get this solution to work for my single falling particle my problem would be easily solved.

Comment: Forgot to mention @gordonbrinkmann, I need to use a particle system because I'm using Forces to dictate the falling leaf particle. When I use rigid body, for whatever reason, the forces will not rotate the object (a question I have on here, yet unanswered), and keyframing the object breaks the physics, so my solution is to use a particle system with some Angular Velocity in order to get the leaf to spin as well as translate.

Comment: @GlenCandle Of course it's not working with particle systems - that's why I'm talking about rigid bodies. Why should I post an answer for particles when you explicitly talk about rigid bodies in the question and have it in the tags? Even when you mention particles in the comments, you go on by saying you got your sim now working fine - which could mean a particle sim, but it could also mean the sim you were talking about in the question. And that's why my answer is here and not on the other question with the particle simulation.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, the fault is all mine. I was merely looking for a solution in general, not necessarily for rigid bodies.  I would happily accept a rigid body solution if there was a way to tumble the leaf as well as move its translation, but sadly this does not seem to be possible.  I'm stuck with a real conundrum: A) I can spin and translate particles, but cannot get keyframes, B) I can get keyframes from a rigid body, but I cannot have the object both spin and translate.  I was not expecting something as simple as tumbling a leaf to be so difficult!